# Несколько SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Добрый день!

Для чего может понадобиться создание нескольких SharedPreferences-xml-файлов в одном приложении?

Спасибо

Comment: Настройки, токены и id пользователя от разных соц. сетей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, первый для зарегистрированных пользователей, а второй для анонимных

Answer (score 2):

Такое может понадобиться, если у вас в ShPr. хранятся даные относящие только к конкретному экрану. Как вариант, можно хранить несколько файлов ShPr. свой для каждого пользователя. Т.е. у вас настройки разных пользователей хранятся в разных файлах, вам нужно програмно только выбрать нужный и настройки подставятся такие какие вам надо.